# Rolling your own WordPress Themes

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am looking to build my own WordPress theme to house my artwork. Can someone point me to the best tutorials for doing so and also give me some pointers on the best approach to building an image gallary?

For example
Should I build a custom gallery?
Is there a suitable plugin that will simplify things?

For background I have a reasonably high level of experience in PHP, HTML5 and CSS3 so have no issues with rolling my own, however I have never built a WordPress theme before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WP Theming** The most important resource for wordpress developers is supplied by the wordpress community themselves: [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/). If you're about to start writing your own theme, the articles on [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) and [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) are a must-read. Also, even though you're just developing for personal use, it might be a good idea to familiarize yourself with the [WordPress Coding Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards).

If you're not all that familiar with wordpress (yet), it would be relatively tedious to write your own theme completely from scratch, i.e. to start with an empty theme folder. For a starting framework, I'd highly recommend checking out the [Starkers Theme](http://starkerstheme.com/) by [Elliot Jay Stocks](http://elliotjaystocks.com/). It is a framework built upon the TwentyTen WordPress theme, stripped off all semantic markup but containing the most essential files and functions a wordpress theme should have.

**Modern Standards, HTML 5 & CSS 3** If you want to write your theme in a modern fashion, i.e. using an HTML 5 doctype as well as semantic HTML 5 structural elements, tools such as [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and [HTML 5 cross-browser polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) can be included into a wordpress theme as they would be in any other ol' website.

**Gallery** As for the gallery, you might want to check out the [NextGEN Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) plugin by [Alex Raabe](http://alexrabe.de/wordpress-plugins/nextgen-gallery/). It is widely used, relatively future proof and can be styled to your personal needs.

Answer (score 0):

Well its great idea that you opted WordPress to build your site, WordPress will provide you full fledged environment to accomplish your requirement.

For image gallery you can do it in many ways even custom build or existing plugins, what i would suggest you is go for plugin since you are new to WordPress.

Here I placed few gallery plugins url just install them and try it out

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slideshow-gallery

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/featured-content-gallery